# Inheriting a python class while adding a property

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-3.x

I'm running into a problem trying to inherit a python class while adding a property. To illustrate, define the following classes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, prop, x1, x2):
        self.prop = prop
        self.x = x1 + x2


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, prop, x1, x2):
        super().__init__(prop, x1, x2)

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self._prop

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        self._prop = value + 10
```

Now class `B` wants to call class `A`'s `__init__` method, which will call `B.prop`'s setter. But I don't want to do this, instead I want to set `_prop` directly. Is there a good way to achieve this?

The following is a solution I've come up with by trying to detect if we're in `__init__` or not, but I'd like to hear some alternatives.

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, prop, x1, x2):
        super().__init__(prop, x1, x2)

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self._prop

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        if hasattr(self, '_prop'):
            self._prop = value + 10
        else:
            self._prop = value
```

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to imagine a use-case for this...? Would you mind explaining what you're trying to achieve? It might lead to broader input into a design pattern you're after.

Comment: I get your point, it's kinda hard but I'll try to give of a more concrete use case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you are seeking is a way to expose implementation details of the child class, `B`, to a method of the parent class, `A.__init__`. I would call that very much an **anti-pattern** rather than a desirable one.

If the behavior of the parent class's `__init__` (setting `self.prop`) doesn't work with the implementation of the child class, then you should rewrite `__init__` in the child class so as not to call the `super().__init__`.

I agree with [Jon Clements' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634031/inheriting-a-python-class-while-adding-a-property/25634120#comment40051330_25634031). What is your code's goal, exactly? Typically, one creates a class to encapsulate some useful behavior. It makes sense to inherit from that class when the child class borrows heavily from the behavior of the parent and can do so without mucking around too much with the internals of the parent.